# Dotted Java JAR Naming Convention

Tags: java, jar

I read in Sun official documentation (or Sun online tutorial) about dotted naming for jar archives.
Was it ever encouraged to name jar artifacts like *com.company.project.smallestdistributable.jar*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this happens from time to time because the dotted naming convention can simulate a namespace within a system that doesn't really handle namespaces.

In your case, you would be simulating the "com.company.project" namespace within the filesystem, with a resolution of "smallestdistributable.jar".

No Java documentation I have ever read (that's since about 1.2) has ever suggested using a naming system like this *for JAR files*.  While one cannot know for sure why it was never recommended, one can guess.  Earlier systems did not see the dotted extension as simply a part of the name, but sometimes saw them as a classifier.  In the earliest systems, names and classifiers had very tight constraints on how many characters were allowed, and only a pattern of [NAME].[CLASSIFIER] was permitted by the file system.  A JAR file (by the way, it's 3 characters because if you wanted file names to be portable, that's the longest classifier available on the filesystem with the shortest classifiers) that contained an extra period would break the filesystem's understanding of the file, so

```
com.company.project.smallestdistributable.jar
```

would be seen as

```
file: com
extension: company.project.smallestdistributable.jar
```

except actually it wouldn't even get that far, because extensions could not have extensions.

I have seen some newer projects, that don't concern themselves with [8].[3] naming conventions add the namespace to the jar file name, but it seems to be a new idea, and not something that was explicitly promoted outside of those development areas.

Comment: This approach is successfully used in Eclipse and I was pretty confident I've read this in Sun online tutorial but fail to find anything like this now. Years ago when C# was grabbing all theirs good ideas from java I was proud that java had it firs (have seen this approach used for C# DLLs also). I was always wondered why projects like maven don't follow this rule because despite all libraries live fine together in repository, once deployed to execution environment you always have some risk of non unique names (it really happened for one of projects I was engaged to).

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych I'm rather (100%) confident that this approach is __not__ in any Sun online tutorial, as I have __only__ seen this in Eclipse, and SUN directs people to not include oddities that make their Java _less_ portable, like naming it something that cannot exist on a [8].[3] file system.  Perhaps you have seen the technique used elsewhere and are misidentifying it with file names, as it is _promoted_ by SUN in many circumstances, but not circumstances including file names.